# Will Facebook continue to support using App Key instead of App ID?

Tags: facebook, api

I have an app that I developed a while ago and I've been using it's "App Key" for the API. I've noticed that on https://developers.facebook.com/apps, it's displaying a different value for App Id/App Key that is a shorter integer than my "App Key," which is a 32 character hex value. I'm guessing that Facebook wants people to use App Ids, but I'm wondering if it will ever stop supporting my old App Key. Anyone know if Facebook has announced anything regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be deprecated silently, instead of announcing like `https` issue. The best way you deprecate you `App Key` before them. If you can't have such opportunity, the best is check sometimes if it works time to time. But may be @Igy may have more clear answer. Good luck

Comment: Is the ID interchangeable for the Key?